# Checkbox coloring

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to C#. I've developed a small program that is similar to Hangman... Here is my issue : I can't find any working commands that will change the color of my Check-box.

Here is the code of my program [The actual code is working where the comments are is where I want to understand how to change the colors of the Check-box] :

```
        public void voirSiLettre(char lettre)
    {
        if (motRechercher.Contains(lettre))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < motRechercher.Length; i++)
            {
                if (motRechercher[i].Equals(lettre))
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(txtMot.Text);
                    sb[i] = lettre;
                    txtMot.Text = sb.ToString();
                }
            } //CheckBox --> Green
        }
        else
        {
            //CheckBox --> Red
        }
    }
```

Here is the code of a Check-box incase you wanted it :

```
    private void chkA_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        voirSiLettre('a');
        chkA.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

It's pretty simple but I can't find the good commands and/or how to place it in this code. I am not asking for a code, maybe just a command with some explanation; I am here to learn.

Comment: Do you want to change the text or the background colour?

Answer (score 1):

To change the background colour of a checkbox you can use Checkbox.Background = Brush, in your case it would be

```
chkA.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

This works fine if you are dealing with the checkbox without it changing state, however if you set it to green and then the user checks the box, it will stay green unless you handle the change in your checked event.

The other alternative is to look at adding a style in your xaml such as:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Name="test">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

You could then use that as the normal background and modify it in code when you wanted to change it to red.

Comment: Ty for the command! My only problem is that the way you wrote it means I have to copy paste it in every checkbox (I have 26... whole alphabet), is there a way to set it, like in the code I provided?

Comment: There problem with the way your code is, is that it is searching through the characters and not the checkbox objects. It is therefore difficult to just change the checkbox color from that code because it does not see an instance of the object. There are a few things you could look at. 1. search a collection of checkboxes to find those that are checked and then assign the color value in that logic. 2. Replace your current chkA_Checked etc so they all point to the same event i.e. checkbox_checked and have the character as the ID in your xaml code. You would then only have the 1 event to maintain